# DotNetNuke7:-Web Api is not triggering on call

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke-6

I have implemented a module using  Angular Js and TypeScript in DotNetNuke7 where i have implemented my all Input Forms and js in a web project named as customerNew and than added a Web APi into a another project named as CustomerNewController which is having my methods but when i hit the URL from my Web Project to Api.It doesn't processed.I have implemented a route mapper as well but still not able get success.

My Route Mapper Class is Given Below:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DotNetNuke.Web.Api;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


namespace CustomerNewController
{
    class RouteMapper : IServiceRouteMapper
    {
        public void RegisterRoutes(IMapRoute mapRouteManager)
        {
            mapRouteManager.MapHttpRoute("CustomerNewController", "default", "{controller}/{action}",
                new[] { "CustomerNewController" });
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my WebApi

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using DotNetNuke.Entities.Users;
using System.Web.Services;
using DotNetNuke.Web.Api;
using DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities;
using DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.Communications;
using DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules;    

namespace CustomerNewController
{
    public class CreateController : DnnApiController
    {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage HelloWorld()
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello World!");
        }
}}
```

My URL

```
http://localhost/dnn7/DesktopModules/CustomerNewController/Api/Create/HelloWorld
```

Here is my folder structure
[image: Folder Structure]

Comment: Please share exact error code you receive - 404 or 500?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**An example of my WebAPI GET method:**

```
[DnnExceptionFilter]
public class AuthorController : DnnApiController
{
    #region Public RPC Methods

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetAllAuthors()
    {
        var lstAuthors = AuthorRepository.GetAllAuthors();
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, lstAuthors);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetAlphabet()
    {
        var lstAuthors = AuthorRepository.GetAlphabet();
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, lstAuthors);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**Service route mapper example (only need to do this once):**

```
public class ServiceRouteMapper : IServiceRouteMapper
{
    #region IServiceRouteMapper Implementation

    public void RegisterRoutes(IMapRoute mapRouteManager)
    {
         mapRouteManager.MapHttpRoute("ATKV.Commerce", "default", "{controller}/{action}", new[] { "ATKV.Commerce.Services" });
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Calling code:

```
// Service Paths
    var servicesFramework = opts.servicesFramework;
    var servicePath = servicesFramework.getServiceRoot('ATKV.Commerce') + 'Author/';
// Bind data
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        url: servicePath + "GetAllAuthors",
        beforeSend: servicesFramework.setModuleHeaders
    }).done(function (authors) {
        if (typeof authors !== "undefined" && authors != null) {
            var viewModel = new MasterViewModel(authors);
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById($(containerElement).attr('id')));
        } else {
            displayMessage("An error occurred", "dnnFormError");
        }
    }).fail(function (xhr, status) {
        displayMessage(status, "dnnFormError");
        return null;
    });
```